# Java generic T extends Object

Tags: java, generics

Given the following class:

```
public class TestMap<K,V> {
    private HashMap<K,V> map;
    public void put(K k, V v) {
        map.put(k, v);
    }
    public V get(K k) {
        return map.get(k);
    }
}
```

and this function:

```
static<T extends Object> String getObj(TestMap<T, String> m, String e) {
    return m.get(e);
}
```

Why does "get" show this error:
`The method get(T) in the type MyHashMap<T,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

When `getObj` states `T extends Object`, and the map has been initialized with `TestMap<T, String> m`, why can't String be used as parameter? I cant wrap my head around why this doesnt work, as String is a subtype of Object ?

I tried extending T from a custom superclass and using a subclass instead of String.

Comment: For starters `T extends Object` is the same as just `T`

Comment: The `String e` param is not necessarily the key type. The type key is T, which may be String, but may also be literally anything else.

Answer (score 2):

`get()` requires as an argument a key, which is of type `T`, not `String`.

So either you need to change `e` to type `T` or change the type of the `Map`, e.g., to `TestMap<String, T>`.

Comment: In other words, `e` needs to be of type `T`, right?

Comment: Well, not *necessarily* String. T may sometimes be String. The problem is that it's not always String.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes.

Comment: @rolve ok, it may be worthwhile to specify that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generics describe what an Object is, `List<String> strings` is a list of `String`s. That gives us some convenience, we don't have to cast. `String s = strings.get(0);` and we get some compile-time protection. `Integer i = 1;` then `strings.add(i);` fails to compile.

The error you are getting is a compile time protection. The key you're providing is an Object, so it *might* be the correct type. In the case of a map, "why not check?" It is just going to hashcode and check for equality which is ok. In the case of a List though, `strings.add((Object)i);` *needs to fail*.

If the doesn't fail, then later something might call. `for(String s: strings)` and get a class cast exception.

To fix this you can change you `V get(K k)` method to a `V get(Object k)` the same as map uses. **Your get method requires type `K` a map normally has a get method with a `Object`**

As mentioned "T extends Object" is the same as just "T". You use the extends when you want to put a lower bound on something. `public <T extends Number> int sum(List<T> numbers)`. In this case "T" can be any class that extends numbers. We can do `Number n = numbers.get(0);` because we know it is *at least* a number. But we could not do `numbers.add(n);` because while `T` is at least a number, it could be something else like an Integer, Double, Number, BigDecimal etc.